# MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm a C#/Windows Forms programmer with more than 5 years experience. I've been investigating WPF using the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) design pattern. I have searched the Internet for tutorials. I have even watched the entirety of Jason Dolinger's awesome video. Although I have found many, I have not found one that takes me from start to finish. What I really want is a tutorial that doesn't assume any previous WPF knowledge.

What are your favorite WPF-MVVM tutorials that helped you to learn?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Your question really seems to be asking 2 questions:

1. Where are some good tutorials on WPF, assuming I have no previous WPF experience?
2. Where are some good tutorials on learning MVVM?

Some of these resources may be duplicated in previous answers...

**Tutorials on WPF**

- [A Guided Tour of WPF by Josh Smith](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/a-guided-tour-of-wpf/)

  > I wrote a series of introductory WPF articles on [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project).  The goal of those articles is to bring someone with no WPF experience up-to-speed enough so that (s)he can fully understand how the series’ demo application works.
- [Bea Stollnitz](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?page_id=47) (link is to her archives) has a number of great articles on WPF.
- [WPF: A Beginner's Guide - Part 1 of n](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF1.aspx) by Sacha Barber
- [WindowsClient.net WPF Training Videos](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx)

**MVVM Tutorials**

- [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) by Josh Smith (duplicate link already provided by Yacoder)
- [Jason Dolinger's presentation on the Model-View-ViewModel](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650) (link to video embedded in article)
- [Dan Crevier's DataModel-View-ViewModel pattern series](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/10/11/datamodel-view-viewmodel-pattern-series.aspx) (similar to MVVM)

**Composite WPF (Prism) Resources**
Though not exactly what you asked, it is the natural progression with WPF and MVVM.

- [Codeplex: Composite WPF (Prism)](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)
- [Silver Bay Labs has a number of great videos on learning Prism](http://development-guides.silverbaylabs.org/home/VideosOnly)
- [Channel 9: 10 step-by-step videos on using Silverlight and Prism](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/mtaulty/Prism--Silverlight-Part-1-Taking-Sketched-Code-Towards-Unity/)
- [Codeplex: Introduction to Composite WPF (CAL, Prism): Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/IntroductionCompositeWPF.aspx) (of n)

Answer (score 44):

I was in exactly the same situation recently, mate, and I can tell you what I did.

[Josh Smith "WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) read again, again and again :-) download the code, examine, compile and keep it around

[MVVM foundation](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/)

1. Examine the framework, use it in your app.
2. Look at the Demo application in that framework.

No real start-to-finish tutorials, sorry...

Comment: +1, this is the article that got me started with MVVM, and it's really good

Comment: I found that article far too bloated and full of fluff to be a useful introduction.  Luckily there's some better examples now such as waf.

Comment: +1 agreed; the mentioned MSDN article is definitely the right way to get started with WPF w/ MVVM

Answer (score 23):

I really liked these articles:

1. [MVVM for Tarded Folks Like Me](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/432/MVVM-for-Tarded-Folks-Like-Me-or-MVVM-and-What-it-Means-to-Me.aspx)
2. [How Tards Like Me Make MVVM Apps](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/433/Anatomy-of-an-MVVM-Application-or-How-Tards-Like-Me-Make-MVVM-Apps.aspx)

He really dumbs down the concept in a humorous way. Worth reading.

Answer (score 15):

[Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358/reed-copsey) published a [nice tutorial](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/) that writes a trivial RSS app in WinForms, then makes a straight port to WPF, and finally converts to MVVM. It makes a nice introduction to MVVM before you try and tackle a full description like [Josh Smith's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). I'm glad that I read Reed's tutorial before Josh's article, because it gives me a little context to understand the details that Josh is digging into.

Answer (score 11):

This one will do:

[RIATasks: A Simple Silverlight CRUD Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/RIATasks.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

I read Josh Smith's article and found it very difficult. Once understood, I wrote a very simple one that should get you really started on it. Get it [here](http://codingtales.com/2010/01/12/getting-started-with-mvvm-in-wpf/).

Comment: I used google to look for a cached version

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zZZ9tr8khHYJ:codingtales.com/2010/01/12/Getting-Started-With-MVVM-in-WPF/+http://codingtales.com/2010/01/12/getting-started-with-mvvm-in-wpf/&cd=1&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=ca

Comment: [This link seems to work](http://codingtales.com/2010/01/12/getting-started-with-mvvm-in-wpf/)

Answer (score 8):

There's a very good Techdays 2010 video introduction to the MVVM pattern, clearly explained:

- [TechDays 2010: Understanding the Model-View-ViewModel pattern](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/kreekman/TechDays-2010-Understanding-the-Model-View-ViewModel-pattern/)

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a tutorial, but it's the diagram on [this](http://www.orbifold.net/default/?p=550) page that helped me get my head around mvvm.

Answer (score 7):

A while ago I was in a similar situation (allthough I had a little WPF knowledge already), so I started a community wiki. There are a lot of great ressources there:

[What applications could I study to understand (Data)Model-View-ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275098/what-applications-could-i-study-to-understand-datamodel-view-viewmodel)

Answer (score 6):

Some blogs/websites to check out:

- [Josh Smith](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/)
- [Dr. WPF](http://www.drwpf.com/blog/)
- [Bea Stollnitz](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/)

Currently, Josh Smith has a "[From Russia With Love](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/the-from-russia-with-love-way-to-create-viewmodels/)" article that can be of some use to you.

Comment: well, the "From Russia With Love" article is pretty good, but I think it's intended for people who already have some knowledge of MVVM...

Comment: +1 for the link to Dr. WPF. His articles, samples and snippets really helped me get up to speed on WPF.

Answer (score 6):

My blog has a complete series of tutorial starting from scratch for WPF MVVM and WPF Prism.
Have a look here:
http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2009/06/03/wpf-and-vmmv-tutorial-01-introduction.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I found http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx as a good start

Answer (score 5):

For something released a little more recently (last month), take a look at Rainer Stropek's video series [MVVM in WPF and Silverlight](http://www.timecockpit.com/en/blogs/10-09-10/time_cockpit_at_NRWConf.aspx)

He flies right through it, but does an extremely good job of going from start to finish with an actual application.

Comment: This is an absolutely fantastic set of videos. Good call.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Jason Dollinger's MVVM video at Lab49](http://www.lab49.com/files/videos/Jason%20Dolinger%20MVVM.wmv).  We have used this in the past to train our team on MVVM.

Answer (score 4):

Don't skip John Papa's presentation from PDC Conference 2010. [See it here](http://videoaz.microsoftpdc.com/vod/downloads/vod/CD50_JohnPapa/CD50_JohnPapa_PDC_MP4_High_1280x720_2500k.mp4).

Answer (score 4):

I have written an application using WPF, Prism and MVVM to simulate hiring a cab,  you can read about it on my blog, download the source [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/sujithkjagini/archive/2011/02/02/building-applications-with-wpf-and-prism-aka-cag.aspx) and play with it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are coming from winforms and  you are looking for a tutorial. I recommend you the MVVM Trainning extension for visual studio: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ab5f02f-0c54-453c-b437-8e8d57eb9942
It´s a tutorial with code examples. 
The tutorial is divided in 3: Basic WPF app, the same app in MVVM and the same using Inversion of control.
Quite useful in your case :)

I also like these ones
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx
http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mvvm/

and this one is with Prism.
http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/10/03/mvvm-with-prism-101-ndash-part-1-the-bootstrapper.aspx
It may be worth it to take a view to Prism if you are thinking to program WPF apps with MVVM

Answer (score 3):

some nice video tutorials here http://live.visitmix.com/Archive

http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/mix/10/wmv-hq/EX14.wmv

http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/mix/10/wmv-hq/EX15.wmv

Answer (score 3):

A very basic tutorial here

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/474/

Answer (score 3):

A good book on MVVM with WPF

[Building Enterprise Applications with Windows® Presentation Foundation and the Model View ViewModel](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0790145309686)

Answer (score 3):

You would love to read these :-

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very good tutorial for MVVM beginners;
http://geekswithblogs.net/mbcrump/archive/2010/06/27/getting-started-with-mvvm-general-infolinks.aspx 
[Getting started with MVVM (General Info+Links)]